# Вопрос по x = yield f() -- какой порядок вызова и присваивания?

Tags: python, python-3.x

объясните, что означает эта строка внутри функции

```
some_variable = yield some_function()
```

если я правильно понимаю, то `yield some_function()` в данном случае отправляет результат в генератор, после чего записывается в переменную и продолжается выполнение кода после этого присваивания.

Если я понял верно, тогда вопрос. А присваивание происходит после того, как происходит возврат и обработка текущего результата, или сначала выполняется до конца текущая функция, затем в генератор возвращается результат?

Comment: связанный вопрос [python generator “send” function purpose?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/19302530/4279)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Если создать генератор `g = gen()`, то сам он ничего не делает, пока снаружи его не продвинут с помощью `next(g)`. *`next(g)` равнозначен `g.send(None)`*.

`g.send(y)` позволяет передать в генератор значение:

```
def gen():
    while True:
        x = yield '.'
        print(x * x)
```

Так как `g = gen()` само по себе не продвигает генератор, то необходимо вызывать `next(g)`, чтобы код дошёл до строчки с `x = yield '.'`. Так как в начале функции нет `yield`, то первый вызов всегда эквивалентен `g.send(None)`. Значения `y`, переданные в последующих вызовах, уже присваиваются `x`:

```
>>> g = gen()
>>> z = g.send(None)
>>> z
'.'
>>> z = g.send(1)
1
>>> z
'.'
>>> z = g.send(2)
4
>>> z
'.'
```

В данном случае генератор генерирует `'.'` постоянно.

Видно, что первый вызов `g.send(None)` не дошёл до `x` (иначе в дальнейшем получили бы TypeError из-за `None * None`). То есть значение переданное в `g.send()` возвращается из `yield`, на котором генератор стоял, а затем код продвигается до следующего `yield` и его аргумент возвращается как результат и присваивается `z`.

Теперь можно объяснить, что происходит с:

```
def gen():
    some_variable = yield some_function()
```

по шагам:

1. Создаём геренратор:

   ```
   >>> g = gen()
   ```

   Код внутри генератора при этом не выполняется
2. Продвигаем код до первого yield, вызывается `some_function()`, получаем значение `some_function()`:

   ```
   >>> g.send(None)
   'result from some_function()'
   ```

   Имя `some_variable` ещё не присвоено по окончанию `g.send()`
3. Следующий вызов `g.send(1)` присваивает `1` к `some_variable` имени и выбрасывает StopIteration, когда код покидает генератор:

   ```
   >>> g.send(1)
   Traceback (most recent call last):
     File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
   StopIteration
   ```

---

Подобные генераторы или как их иногда называют сопрограммы (coroutine) могут использоваться, чтобы перемежать исполнение нескольких функций в одном потоке. Практический пример, можно выполнить `NREQUESTS` сетевых запросов по `NCONCURRENT` одновременных запросов, используя  `twisted.internet.defer.inlineCallbacks` декоратор:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
"""Make NREQUESTS http POST requests `NCONCURRENT` at the time using treq module."""
import os
from twisted.internet import defer, task # $ pip install twisted
import treq                              # $ pip install treq

def n_at_a_time(it, n):
    """Iterate over `it` concurently `n` items at a time.

    `it` - an iterator creating Deferreds
    `n`  - number of concurrent iterations
    return a deferred that fires on completion
    """
    return defer.DeferredList([task.coiterate(it) for _ in range(n)])

@defer.inlineCallbacks
def make_request():
    # post request
    response = yield treq.post('http://localhost:8001/post', {'a':'b', 'c': 'd'})
    data = yield response.content()  # read response

def main(reactor):
    reqs = (make_request() for _ in range(int(os.environ['NREQUESTS'])))
    return n_at_a_time(reqs, n=int(os.environ['NCONCURRENT']))

task.react(main)
```

По похожему, но несколько другому механизму (основанному на `yield from`, а не `yield`) работают asyncio coroutines.

Comment: Как связаны next и send?

Comment: @Qwertiy: цитата: *"next(g) (равнозначно g.send(None))."*

Comment: Я невнимательный...

Answer (score 0):

Вот примерное объяснение:

```
some_function = lambda: 'some_function result'

def func():
    while True:
        value = some_function()
        print('value', value)
        result = yield value
        print('result', result)

g = func()
value = next(g) # инициализация генератора(обязательно), и получение value
value = next(g) # и еще просто получить value
g.send(1) # передаем 1 в генератор, теперь result = 1
value = g.send(2) # передаем 2 в генератор, теперь result = 2. Также получаем value
```

1. То есть если вы хотите просто получить `value` то нужно просто `value = next(g)`.
2. Если хотите установить `result` в `YOU_RESULT` и получить `value` то нужно `value = g.send(YOU_RESULT)`.

Еще учтите, что для `g.send(YOU_RESULT)` необходима первичная инициализация `g` - `next(g)`. Это все дело необходимо для [https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/Сопрограмма](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%A1%D0%BE%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B3%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%BC%D0%BC%D0%B0) Вот собственно и все. Задавайте вопросы если непонятно

Comment: Возможно, во втором print должен быть result, а не res?

Comment: @Qwertiy поправил